# Reativar função jquery após chamada de função

Tags: jquery, funções, formulário, input

Boa tarde, possuo o seguinte código que insere inputs dentro de uma div quando é clicado em um botão "NOVO" que também leva o foco direto para o primeiro campo na linha e que também pode acontecer ao apertar o enter, o problema é, só funciona o enter na primeira linha, as linhas que são inseridas não funciona o enter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var scntDiv = $('#more_item');
var rscn = $('#more_item x').size() + 1;
new_input();
input_keydown();

$('#more_item_add').on('click', function() {
    new_input(); });

function input_keydown() {
    $('input').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            new_input(); } }); }

function new_input() {
    $('<x><input class="cod" id="focus' + rscn +'" placeholder="Código" /><input class="desc" placeholder="Descrição" /><input class="quant" placeholder="Quantidade" /><input class="val" placeholder="Valor" /><span id="remove_item" class="remove cursor_pointer display_none">+</span></x>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    $('#focus' + rscn).focus();
    rscn++;
    return false; }

$('#remove_item').live('click', function() {
    if(rscn > 1) {
        $(this).parents('x').remove();
        rscn--; }
    return false; });

$('#print').on('click', function() {
    window.print(); });

$('#reset').on('click', function() {
    location.reload(); }); });
```

o que no caso atrapalha, pois eu queria ir apertando o enter até o final, ou seja, eu preencho a primeira linha e aperto o enter, ai pulo para a segunda e aperto o enter para a terceira e por ai vai, mas só funciona na primeira.

```
<script src='jquery_1.8.3.js'></script>
<div class='inputs'>
    <div id='more_item_add' class='button cursor_pointer display_none'>Novo</div>
    <div id='print' class='button cursor_pointer display_none'>Imprimir</div>
    <div id='reset' class='button cursor_pointer display_none'>Resetar</div>
    <div id='more_item'></div>
</div>
```

não sei se é o melhor formato, aceito sugestões, mas não gosto de aguardar a resposta sem testar, então procurei muito mesmo depois de perguntar e achei uma solução que ajudou exatamente como precisava, bastou trocar a parte

```
function input_keydown() {
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        new_input(); } }); }
```

por esta parte

```
        $(document).on('keydown', 'input', function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                new_input(); } });
```

Comment: coloca o HTML na pergunta para facilitar.. :)

Comment: achei neste site http://www.kadunew.com/blog/jquery/atribuindo-eventos-a-elementos-criados-dinamicamente

Comment: Da forma como você achou, vai funcionar se o foco estiver nos `inputs` ou não... é assim mesmo?

Comment: @MarllonNasser no caso, quando eu apertar enter estando em um input, quando apertar fora do input ele não executa, tem que estar com foco em um input qualquer, não está especificado qual input, mas isso no caso é proposital pois não quero escolher input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utilizando este trecho, consegui um resultado agradável, mas ainda aceito sugestões

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'input', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
       new_input(); } });
```

e na função de inserção de input eu mudei de append para prepend

```
function new_input() {
    $('<x>'
        + '<input class="cod" placeholder="Código" />'
        + '<input class="desc" placeholder="Descrição" />'
        + '<input id="teste_de_calculo quantidade" class="quant" placeholder="Quantidade" />'
        + '<input id="teste_de_calculo resultado" class="val" placeholder="Valor" />'
        + '<span class="remove cursor_pointer display_none">+</span>'
    + '</x>').prependTo(scnDiv);
    $('input').first().focus();
    rscnDiv++; } });
```